# What is this Common Service Connector "id" in my Logic Apps ARM template and do I need to tokenize it?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, cds

In my Logic Apps ARM template I have a "create record" to a Common Data Service connector.

```
"path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('orgd16*****.crm11'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('contacts'))}/items"
```

I know 'orgd16*****.crm11' is a CDS environment name, so I'm guessing the external API connection doesn't hold the environment ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The external API connection does not hold the environment. The external API connection just authenticates and connects to the service.

Calls to an environment would pass through authorization on the common data service and if the user/service principal has access to the specified environment, it would be allowed.